# How to make Bitfinex api v1 signiture?

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, base64, cryptojs

I am trying to get response from bitfinex authenticated endpoint but I always get error 401: "Invalid X-BFX-SIGNATURE." I am not sure with base64 encoding or with creating hmac. Thank you for help.
bitfinex example:  https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs/rest-auth

Here is my code:
`
request.data =

```
({
      ...request.data,
      request: request.url,
      nonce: Date.now().toString()
    })
    request.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-BFX-APIKEY': config.bitfinex.apiKey,
      'X-BFX-PAYLOAD':     Crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(Crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(request.data))),
      'X-BFX-SIGNATURE': Crypto.HmacSHA384(config.bitfinex.secretKey,      Crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(Crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(request.data)))).toString()      
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which works, I must edit nonce and signature:

```
request.data = JSON.stringify({
  ...request.data,
  request: request.url,
  nonce: (1000 * new Date().getTime()).toString()
})
request.headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-BFX-APIKEY': config.bitfinex.apiKey,
  'X-BFX-PAYLOAD': Crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(Crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(request.data)),
  'X-BFX-SIGNATURE': Crypto.HmacSHA384(Crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(Crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(request.data)),
    config.bitfinex.secretKey)
}
```